# Video is crashing the entire site

Tags: html, angular, video

I am working on a project for a website developed at angular 8 and I have a video at the header of the site, the video weighs around 13mb and loads every time the user enters the page.

The problem is that this video is consuming a lot of ram and cpu memory from the computer, sometimes even the browser crashes.

This happens on all browsers (IE, chrome, mozila) and also on powerful computers (i7, 16gb ram).

Does anyone have an idea how I can do to improve video performance?

To play the video I'm using the html `<video>` tag, below is the code i'm using.

```
<div class="tp-caption tp-fade fadeout fullscreenvideo" data-x="0" data-y="0" data-speed="1000" data-start="1100" data-easing="Power4.easeOut" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.1" data-endspeed="1500" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" data-autoplay="true" data-autoplayonlyfirsttime="false" data-nextslideatend="true" data-volume="mute" data-forcecover="1" data-aspectratio="16:9" data-forcerewind="on" style="z-index: 0;">
    <video class="" preload="none" width="100%" height="100%" poster="assets/videos/test.png">
        <source src="assets/videos/testvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: that size video shouldn't be a problem... can you share a link to show the issues. have you tried removing the surrounding animation class in case that's the root cause of the memory/cpu issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by changing the video format from .mp4 to .webm format.

This gave me a smaller video size and better performance.